# How to diffrentiate between methods and functions?

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a project and applying logistic regression to do a data mining task.
However, I'm asked to define the functions and methods but I'm confused between them. can you help me to assign which one is a function and which one is a method for the following?

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split (1)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42) (2)

confusion_matrix(y_test,predictions) (3)

logmodel.fit(x_train,y_train) (4)

logmodel=LogisticRegression() (5)
```

Comment: _but I'm confused between them_ Can you be more specific? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

A method is a function which is part of a class, so `logmodel.fit()` is a method while `train_test_split()` and `confusion_matrix()` are regular functions.

`LogisticRegression` is a constructor, which is the `def __init__(self, ...)` part of a class.

For demonstration:

```
def thisIsAFunction(a, b):
    return a + b

class ThisIsAClass:
    def __init__(self, x): # this is a constructor
        self.x = x

    def thisIsAMethod(self):
        return self.x
```

Comment: so, is sns.countplot(x="death_or_no", data=data)
 --> sns.countplot() is a method here?

Comment: Variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: I would argue that, while it is true that python libraries follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style, it's up to you to choose what style you use in your code as long as you're consistent.